# R: Merge several columns into one, with one value on each row

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Right now I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Z    A  B  C  D  F
1  82   1 NA NA NA 77
2 454  NA  2 NA NA 18
3 606  NA NA  3 NA 12
4  55  NA NA NA  4 23
5  32  NA  2 NA NA  4
# And many more rows follows
```

Only one of the columns A,B,C,D has value on each row, and the value is the same within each column. I wanted to merge them into one single column, and 1, 2, 3, 4 will become factor levels of this new column.

Desired results:

```
   Z    A  B  C  D  F  E
1  82   1 NA NA NA 77  1
2 454  NA  2 NA NA 18  2
3 606  NA NA  3 NA 12  3
4  55  NA NA NA  4 23  4
5  32  NA  2 NA NA  4  2
# And many more rows follows
# Dropping A,B,C,D as a side-effect is OK
```

I have tried using `ifelse` statements (`data$E = ifelse(data$A == 1, 5, data$A)`, but each `ifelse` statements overwrites the the previous modification, so at the end only level 4s are written into column E.

Is there any elegant way I could merge these columns? Dropping A,B,C,D as a side-effect is OK. Thanks!

EDIT: What if I have more columns to the left and the right that are irrelevant? Is some sort of slicing required? (See edited code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there's only one value for each row, `rowSums` will work:

```
df$E <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)

df
##    A  B  C  D E
## 1  1 NA NA NA 1
## 2 NA  2 NA NA 2
## 3 NA NA  3 NA 3
## 4 NA NA NA  4 4
## 5 NA  2 NA NA 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have extra columns in my df that is not relevant to this newly built column? Would I need to slice the columns out first to get it done?

Comment: Subset the `df` in the call: `rowSums(df[ , 2:5], na.rm = T)`

Comment: Thanks, I did it a in a dumber way ``df$E <- colSums(df[c("A", "B", "C", "D")], na.rm = T)`` Works well now.

Comment: That's fine. Especially if you've got a lot of columns, subsetting with names can be a safer and less confusing way to go.

Answer (score -3):

We can use `pmax` or `pmin` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
df1$E <- do.call(pmax, c(df1, na.rm=TRUE))
df1
#   A  B  C  D E
#1  1 NA NA NA 1
#2 NA  2 NA NA 2
#3 NA NA  3 NA 3
#4 NA NA NA  4 4
#5 NA  2 NA NA 2
```

---

We can also use `max.col` (in this example we don't need to `cbind` with the row index)

```
max.col(!is.na(df1))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 2
```

In general

```
df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), max.col(!is.na(df1)))]
```

Or we can use  `%*%` to get the column index of non-NA elements per each row

```
(+(!is.na(df1)) %*% seq_along(df1))[,1]
```

---

If we are using `hadleyverse`, the `coalesce` can help as well

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     mutate(E = coalesce(A, B, C, D))
#   A  B  C  D E
#1  1 NA NA NA 1
#2 NA  2 NA NA 2
#3 NA NA  3 NA 3
#4 NA NA NA  4 4
#5 NA  2 NA NA 2
```

---

Or another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, E := na.omit(unlist(.SD)) ,1:nrow(df1)]
```

NOTE: This solutions were based on the OP's initial example/expected output and also the `title` of this post **R: Merge several columns into one, with one value on each row**

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(NA, 2L, NA, NA, 
2L), C = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA), D = c(NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"))
```